# How to prove $q=f(x)-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2$ is $(L-m)$-Lipschitz if $f$ is $m$-strongly convex with $L$-Lipschitz?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am learning this book: [*Optimization for Data Analysis*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/optimization-for-data-analysis/C02C3708905D236AA354D1CE1739A6A2). I am not familiar with calculating the Euclidean norm, and it is too abstract for me. So, I am struggling with [the exercise 8-(a) in Chapter 2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/8442E85ADF1B9FC53006F97B40EB029C/stamped-9781316518984c2_15-25.pdf/foundations_of_smooth_optimization.pdf):

Suppose that $f$: $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an $m$-strongly convex function with $L$-Lipschitz gradient and (unique) minimizer $x^*$ with function value $f^* = f (x^*)$. Show that the function $q(x) := f (x)− \frac{m}{2}||x||^2$ is convex with $(L−m)$-Lipschitz continuous gradients.

The convexity can be directly proved by the definition of $m$-strongly convexity. However, it is hard to prove that it is $(L−m)$-Lipschitz continuous gradients. I try to simplify
$$||\nabla q(x)-\nabla q(y)||=||\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)-m(x-y)||,$$
and apply triangle inequality : $||a\pm b|| \le ||a||+||b||$, but it can not prove it.

How can this part be proved? Please give any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: **Hint**: First try proving that a convex $f$ is $L$-smooth if and only if it satisfies $\langle x - y, \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \rangle \leq L\|x - y\|^2$ for all pairs $x, y$. Then the claim of the exercise follows almost automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I might get the proof:

First, we have
$$
\nabla q(x) = \nabla f(x) -mx,
$$
and
$$
2<x_0,x> + ||x-x_0||^2-||x||^2-||x_0||^2= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow m<x_0,x> + \frac{m}{2}||x-x_0||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2= 0
$$
Since $f$ is with $L$-Lipschitz gradient, we have
$$
f(x)\le f(x_0)+<\nabla f(x_0), x-x_0> + \frac{L}{2}||x-x_0||^2.
$$
For above inequality, add $0$ on the left-hand side, and add $m<x_0,x> + \frac{m}{2}||x-x_0||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2$ on the right-hand side, i.e.,
$$f(x)\le f(x_0)+<\nabla f(x_0), x-x_0> + \frac{L}{2}||x-x_0||^2 - (m<x_0,x> + \frac{m}{2}||x-x_0||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2).
$$
Easy to prove that
$$
<\nabla f(x_0), x-x_0> - (m<x_0,x> + \frac{m}{2}||x-x_0||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2)= \frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2+<\nabla f(x_0)-mx_0, x-x_0> - \frac{m}{2}||x-x_0||^2.
$$
So, we can get
$$
f(x)\le f(x_0)+\frac{m}{2}||x||^2-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2+<\nabla f(x_0)-mx_0, x-x_0> + \frac{L-m}{2}||x-x_0||^2\\
\Leftrightarrow f(x)-\frac{m}{2}||x||^2\le f(x_0)-\frac{m}{2}||x_0||^2+<\nabla f(x_0)-mx_0, x-x_0> + \frac{L-m}{2}||x-x_0||^2\\
\Leftrightarrow q(x)\le q(x_0)+<\nabla q(x_0), x-x_0> + \frac{L-m}{2}||x-x_0||^2.\\
$$
Because $q(x)$ is convex, the above inequality is an equivalent Lipschitz continuous gradient condition with $(L-m)$-Lipschitz gradient.